# when i trying to use apt-get update . this happens

Tags: kali-linux, repository

```
Err:1 http://your.repo.domain/repository kali-rolling InRelease
  Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Ign:4 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/moritzmolch:/gencfsm/Debian_9.0  InRelease
Hit:6 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/moritzmolch:/gencfsm/Debian_9.0  Release
Hit:7 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://your.repo.domain/repository/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `your.repo.domain` can clearly not be resolved. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: then how to remove this error

Comment: Maybe don’t blindly copy/paste random instructions for adding repos?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 5):

Kali Linux Documentation says:

> The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating the system’s sources.list file with unofficial repositories. The following post aims to clarify what repositories should exist in sources.list, and when they should be used.
>
> Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.

Source: https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories